# Numpy pColormesh TypeError: Dimensions of C are incompatible with X and/or Y see help(pcolormesh)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm currently working on an assignment and have to use pColormesh to make a figure. Here is the code that causes the error.

```
Fz_idx = ch_names.index("Fz") 
Fz_evoked_exp = TFR_evoked_exp_norm[:,Fz_idx,:,:,:] 

Fz_evoked_control = TFR_evoked_control_norm[:,Fz_idx,:,:,:]

        
Fz_evoked_exp_log = np.log10(Fz_evoked_exp) 
Fz_evoked_control_log = np.log10(Fz_evoked_control)
    
Fz_TFR_exp = np.nanmean(Fz_evoked_exp_log, axis = 0) 
Fz_TFR_control = np.nanmean(Fz_evoked_control_log, axis = 0)
    
Fz_TFR_exp_part1 = Fz_TFR_exp[:,:,0] 
Fz_TFR_control_part1 = Fz_TFR_control[:,:,0]
    
intersection_time = int(window_step*(1.5))/int(len(time)) 
time_evoked = [] 
for x in range(25, nWindows):
   time_evoked.append(-0.5+ (x*intersection_time))



fig_Q10, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4), nrows=1, ncols=2) # 1x2 graph

ctrl = ax[0].pcolormesh(time_evoked, spect_freqs , (Fz_TFR_control_part1), vmin=-0.5, vmax=0.5, cmap='jet') exp = ax[1].pcolormesh(time_evoked, spect_freqs , (Fz_TFR_exp_part1), vmin=-0.5, vmax=0.5, cmap='jet')

fig_Q10.colorbar(ctrl, ax=ax[0]) fig_Q10.colorbar(exp, ax=ax[1]) plt.show()
```

time_evoked is a list of size 26, spect_freqs is a numpy array with shape(126,) and Fz_TFR_control/exp_part1 are numpy arrays with shape(26,126). I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Dimensions of C (26, 126) are incompatible with X (26) and/or Y (126); see help(pcolormesh)
```

I don't understand why this happens as the dimensions seem fine to me. What do you think is causing the problem and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to transpose C.

Comment: Apart from the transposition problem, note that a mesh needs one row and one column of coordinates more than color values. You will need 127 x-values and 27 y-values, as these define the edge positions.  Also note that [`jet` is usually frowned upon](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/).

Comment: @JohanC You were right, it worked! Also, thanks for the heads up about jet, didn't know it was not that great. :)

Comment: @JodyKlymak Yes, that was the major issue, thank you!